# UpdateProgress not unlocking screen when tab changed

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a UserControl having UpdateProgress and ProgressTemplate contains an IFrame and  showing *wait while processing.* message.

**Issue**:
When I click on Save, *wait while processing.* comes, but just after clicking Save(), if I migrate to different tab and again come back to my Saving page, the page gets saved, but *wait while processing.* doesnot go and screen is in locked state.

**Findings**
I tried the following code to see if my request finish's or not,

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
 function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
 }
 function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
     alert('finished');
 }
);
```

It did show 'finished'.

**Occasions**

Interestingly the issue is only happening when I access my ASP page through IP address and NOT through http://localhost/page.aspx.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!